# excel: what is the formula to add comma, single quotes before and after the text in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Cell A1 to Axx i have numbers in this format 777777777

the end result should he '255777777777',

Can someone tell me the formula i need to use to automatically get  '255  and ',  added to the numbers in cells A1 to Axx.

Comment: `="255"&A1&","`

Comment: If you are trying to use a cell format, you can use the following custom format: `"'255"#"',"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the cell formula you are looking for: ="'255" & A1 & "',"

Comment: thanks. what would be the formula if there is already a 2557777777 in the cell and i only want to add ' ',

Comment: It adds the '255 to the front too.  Only 77777777 needs to be in A1.

Comment: yeah. but for some cases if i try with 2557777777 in A1 and only want ' ', added. the answer you gave me is giving correct result. but just wanted to know the formula without 255 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if you also want to check if the value already has 255 in it:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(255,A1,1)=1,A1&","), "255"&A1&",")
```

Comment: even better. but this doesn't add the ' '. it's only adding a , after the number and not '2557777777', complete thing.

Comment: Ok so change the "," in the formula for " ".